# CMake - adding options to Makefile

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake

Lately I have hit the wall with generating arguments for `Makefile`, to not waste your time lets go to example (straight from my `CMakeLsits.txt`)

```
EXTERNALPROJECT_ADD( GTEST
                 GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/google/googletest
                 CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${GTEST_INSTALL_LOCATION}
                 GIT_SHALLOW TRUE
                 UPDATE_DISCONNECTED TRUE
                 )
```

And here I have 2 params which I desire to change on make run (fe. `make build offline`), to **not force myself to generate Makefile every time** I change work place (I just want to write switch/flag) and change value of `UPDATE_DISCONNECTED` or any parameter in Makefile.

Is that possible?
If so, How?

I would be really grateful on explanation, to let myself learn more about cmake and it's behavior (doc page is more than enough :] ).

Comment: As far as I know, if you want to change an option value, you have to regenerate the Makefiles.

Comment: I do know this method, but It is highly.... hmmm annoying? I just find it stupid to use cmake command every time I change place i am at (home -> college -> company, etc). And that is why I am looking for solution to such an simple problem (It is much easier to write `make build --offline` or something similar.

I know I could technically use targets, to achieve that, but it feels wanky.

Comment: If it's a value from the environment, then it could work, but it has to be done outside of CMake (otherwise CMake would replace the value by the value at CMake time, not at runtime).

Comment: This is... Good. Man, how did I not think about that! Thank you!

Comment: "... any problem in computing can be solved by adding another layer of indirection ..." :)